# Compute component of a Quaternion with an assumption

Tags: syntax, quaternions

I am really new to mathematica and the syntax sometimes is a bit hard for me. I come from Matlab environment. I think this question is really easy for the most of you.

I am trying to use quaternions in Mathematica and I wrote the following code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
<< Quaternions`
q1 = Quaternion[q_t, q_x, q_y, q_z];
q2 = Conjugate[q1];
A = Quaternion[0, A_x, A_y, A_z];
totQuat1 = Simplify[q1 ** A ** q2]
```

Everything seems right to me and I get:

```
Quaternion[0,A_x (q_t^2+q_x^2-q_y^2-q_z^2)+2 (A_y (q_x q_y-q_t q_z)+A_z (q_t q_y+q_x q_z)),A_y (q_t^2-q_x^2+q_y^2-q_z^2)+2 (A_x (q_x q_y+q_t q_z)+A_z (-q_t q_x+q_y q_z)),A_z (q_t^2-q_x^2-q_y^2+q_z^2)+2 (A_x (-q_t q_y+q_x q_z)+A_y (q_t q_x+q_y q_z))]
```

**But now I would like to take the second element of the quaternion and set A_x to 0.**

I am trying to do:

```
A_x=0
totQuat1[[2]]
```

But what I get is the second component of the quaternion and the A_x is not set to 0.

```
A_x (q_t^2 + q_x^2 - q_y^2 - q_z^2) + 
 2 (A_y (q_x q_y - q_t q_z) + A_z (q_t q_y + q_x q_z))
```

How can I do that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You cannot have underscores in variable names in *Mathematica*. `_`, i.e. [`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html) has a special meaning used in pattern matching. Try without them and see if your code works differently.

Comment: Yeah it was that. I did not know this rule. 

Thanks.